# Multiple solutions application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm planning to create a website using ASP.NET Core 2.0 , Entity Framework Core, Angular.

I was planning to create one solution with different projects (core, data layer, UI ...etc ) however the client quoted "this is a bad idea, please create separate solution for your UI and API).

how can i create multiple solution and still let them interact with each others?
What is the best practice?
If i create separate solution for my UI, how can i communicate with EF context which is in a different solution?

Comment: This was a lol moment for me :P, anyway your UI, which is in Angular should not in anyway communicate with EF... it communicates with the API using HttpClient.

Comment: My guess is that client don't want everything in the same project like [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-co-crud-using-angular-5-and-entity-framework/). And want at least 2 project for API and UI. Not saying that it's bad,  tutorial are easier when everything is in the same project.

Comment: Your angular app will communicate with your api over http. So the api and the angular app can be split into seperate solutions without a problem. Your api then calls entity framework.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is basically just a logical container for projects, so you can create multiple solutions which will reference the same (existing) projects. This is quite common for large solutions like for example [Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms) - you can have one large solution with all projects and then have smaller solutions for developers who need to work with only a subset of the projects.

You can add existing project to your solution by right-clicking the solution in **Solution Explorer** and choosing **Add** - **Existing Project**.

Answer (score 1):

I think your client may misunderstand what a solution is. Grouping your projects in a solution only affects your workspace in Visual Studio, it does not mean that your projects have dependencies between them (unless you explicitely say so in their references)

Comment: That could very well be the case, unless the client is a tech client who is purchasing the code after the fact, and insists on separate solutions as the product deliverable. (I've seen stranger things.)

Comment: It's even weirder due to the fact that they could easily create another Solution and add the UI project to that solution afterwards. So unless they want to make their developers suffer, I don't see any reason to split solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can imagine this working is to deliver each solution as a set of microservices.

However, now your architecture is different. Only one of those solutions is going to be publicly exposed. The others will need to sit behind a firewall to ensure that they can't be reached by external users. But all of them will have scalability and security concerns.

So you'll have a set of data services that encapsulate Entity Framework and expose the data through a Web API, and a business logic API that is reached over a Web API, and then your UI (which should include Angular).

APIs calling APIs. Welcome to microservices.

Comment: He's asking about splitting the angular frontend from the api with seperate solutions. I don't see the extreme architectural problem here... Just split the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

how can i create multiple solution and still let them interact with each others? What is the best practice? If i create separate solution for my UI, how can i communicate with EF context which is in a different solution?

Answer :

1. Create base solution first ex : BaseSolution.sln then go to that solution file explorer and create API,UI folder.
2. Now open visual studio and create new solution ex: ApiSolution.sln save it under API folder and add web api project inside ApiSolution.sln and save.
3. Now open BaseSolution.sln and right-clicking the solution in Solution Explorer and choosing Add - Existing Project then choose web api project from ApiSolution.sln then add it.
   You can follow step 2 and 3 to create more solution and add it to BaseSolution.
   Web api connect through HTTPClient with another web api.